# Remove a compute node in Openstack

Tags: openstack, host, kvm, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I am having trouble removing a compute node from openstack newton.
I am not able to deploy instances after trying to remove the host with these commands:

```
openstack compute service delete {{id}}
neutron agent delete {{id}}
```

Is there a another way or additional steps to remove the host?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the output of from `openstack compute service list` in a comment. Is the host listed that you are trying to remove? Also, did you remove the compute node from the environment, or is nova-compute still running on it? What error message you are receiving when you attempt to deploy a new instance? Do you have other hosts available with enough resources to handle the new instances?

Answer (score 0):

...a step-by-step detailed how-to can also be found at the INFN website here: https://wiki.infn.it/progetti/cloud-areapd/operations/production_cloud/remove_a_compute_node_howto

What they basically suggest is to "manually" remove the relevant records from the database, after having disabled the services on the node and migrated out its instances.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the instructions in the below link

https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/97941/how-to-remove-compute-host-in-controller-unfortunately-i-removed-that-host-but-name-still-available/

Comment: I saw this post already. I cannot preform this step:
mysql>DELETE FROM compute_node_stats WHERE compute_node_id='1';
I cannot find this table. I think it is deprecated.